# Android: setting file association without opening the app

Tags: android, android-intent, picker, file-association

My Android app has to allow the user choose which app will open a certain file format, exploiting the system chooser, so next time a certain intent is handled as the user decided.

I would like that it is able to open a chooser of apps for an intent but without opening the chosen app.

I mean, the chooser has to be called just to have the user choosing the app but the app wouldn't open.

Is it possible, maybe with a special intent or workaround?

Comment: I am fairly certain that this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a little bit like the one feature in "Android for Work", maybe you can check it.